# Can someone explain the diction in the error: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'..."?

Tags: iis, cors

I know this issue is all over stack overflow and there are a lot of solutions to it, but my questions is regarding the phrasing of the error itself and what certain parts mean. Here is the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://microsoft.com' 
(redirected from 'https://apple.com') 
from origin 'https://apple.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is this saying the Microsoft received or sent an `XMLHttpRequest`?

Is the originator of the `XMLHttpRequest` Apple?

I am very confused about what domain this error is stating that the `XMLHttpRequest` came from!

Comment: Learn to use developer tools of your web browser to track down the various HTTP requests/responses and then you can tell which web server(s) replies with what messages. You got confused because you didn't actually look at the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

> Is this saying the Microsoft received or sent an `XMLHttpRequest`?

Microsoft received the request.

> Is the originator of the `XMLHttpRequest` Apple?

Yes.

---

### More details

I'm assuming that the error message in your question is fictitious and that the URL and origins mentioned are there just as an example. You can read the error message as follows:

> from origin 'https://apple.com' has been blocked by CORS policy

Understand: Some page on Web origin `https://apple.com` issued a cross-origin request that failed the CORS check.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://microsoft.com' (redirected from 'https://apple.com')

Understand: The request was issued to `https://apple.com`, which resulted in a cross-origin redirect to `https://microsoft.com`.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Understand: The cross-origin request to `https://microsoft.com` was such as to trigger a CORS check, but CORS preflight failed because `https://microsoft.com` isn't configured to allow Web origin `https://apple.com`.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared it up perfectly!